# Light pollution and visibility of Milky way

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, light-pollution

Say, 1000 years ago, when there was (almost) no light pollution or air pollution, would the milky-way galaxy have been visible at night, anywhere on Earth?

Comment: If you were standing next to an open fire at night, you wouldn't have seen the milky way very well even back then, so light pollution is not exactly a new problem. If you are in the tropics at sea level, visibility of the night sky is compromised, even in the darkest locations because of frequent cloud cover and high atmospheric moisture content. Geometrically parts of our galaxy should be visible from any location on Earth. Is there a particular scenario that you are thinking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie it is about physics, since the ability of light to penetrate the atmosphere in a way that is visible to humans inherently involves  physical principles

Comment: @Sekots: ultimately everything involves physical principles, but that doesn't make every question about physics.